# JQuery script not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have a function I have been working on.  While I was getting things working I had it as a script on my main html page and it was all working fine.  Then I moved it to my external .js file and it stopped so I moved it back to the html file and it still doesn't do anything.  I have used IE developer tools to verify that the `<select name="Branch" id="Branch" onchange="BookingUpdate">` event is actually calling the script.

Now for the really weird bits.

1. I tried renaming the function - no change
2. I created a new script with only an alert saying hello - didn't do anything
3. I tried attaching the function to an onchange on a different input - didn't work
4. I clear cache on both my browsers and server - no change
5. I tried different browsers - no difference in behaviour

I have a few JQuery UI widgets running on the same page so JQuery is defiantly working.

```
    <script>
       function BookingUpdate(){
          var offices = <?php echo json_encode($row_offices); ?>;
                var branchindex = getKeyByID(offices, $("#Branch").val());
                var days = ["Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"];
                var i, row='';
                for (i=0;i<7;i++){
                    var d = new Date($("#BookingDate").val());
                    var dloop = d.addDays(i-3);
                    row += '<td align=center><h3>'+days[dloop.getDay()]+'<br>'+(dloop.getMonth()+1)+'/'+dloop.getDate()+'</h3></td>';
                }
                $('#BookingCal > tbody:last').append('<tr>' + row + '</tr>');
          }
     </script>
```

Comment: Is the function in a `$(document).ready()`? What does your `script` tag look like? Where is your `script` tag (in the `head` or in the `body` somewhere)?

Comment: ok so I've added the script tags for you.  When it was in the external .js file it  was being called from an onchange event in `$(document).ready()` but now that it is back in the html it is the last thing in my body.

Comment: Firstly thanks jsve for at least giving me some questions to get me thinking.  That is one of the main reasons I come here to get someone else's thought so I think about the problem from a different direction.  Secondly the problem is that something is stopping the `onChange` event from happening the browser processes it but doesn't actually run the function.  I tested this by running the function as `$(document).ready` and it works fine.

Comment: Here is the code on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aarontharker/o7awf0br/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue here was that I was using the old fashion javascript onchange event with a JQuery script.  Apparently the 2 don't like to play together.  As soon as I change it to use a `JQuery $('#Branch').on('change', function() {` in my document ready script it worked fine.